# Tailwind how to show div on click when device is small

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css

I have simple 2 divs. When device is small on second div is showing with menu icon. What I want is when I click on menu button the first div should appear as overflow/sidepopup

I also created a tailwind play link https://play.tailwindcss.com/2msoAWR8rp

You can see if device is medium or large there is section of messages and when device is small it will hide and menu icon appear on second div. Now I am not able to show first div like overflow or some kind of slider.

Preview when device small first is hiding I need to show this when I click on icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you can start the solution by giving the sidebar a certain width. Then you need to ensure that the sidebar is present as a block on large screens, but 40 units to the left on small screens (40 = sidebar width). After all, you can clarify this problem with a simple javascript code by giving the button an id to the sidebar. Hope it helps, happy new year :)

Please review the code on the full page.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="flex flex-row max-h-screen">
    <!-- hidden w-full md:block md:w-auto -->
    <div class="mt-8 ml-5 w-40 max-md:-ml-40 md:block" id="navbar-default">

      <div class="mt-4 h-5/6 overflow-y-scroll" data-collapse-toggle="navbar-default">
        <div class="cursor-pointer">
          <div class=" py-2 px-2">
            <div class="flex justify-between pb-3">
              <div class="flex">

                <div class="flex flex-col pl-2">
                  <div class="font-bold text-base">
                    john
                  </div>
                  <div class="font-normal text-xs pt-1">
                    hye
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex flex-col items-end">
                <div class="font-medium text-xs">
                  24may
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-grow border-t border-gray-200"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-col">
      <div class=" h-full w-0.5 ml-4 mr-4 flex-grow bg-gray-200"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-9/12 mt-5 mb-5 mr-5">
      <div class=" bg-white shadow-lg rounded-2xl  h-full flex flex-1 flex-col justify-between">
        <div>
          <div class="flex justify-between p-4">
            <div class="flex">
              <div id="button" class="flex md:hidden " data-bs-target="navbar-d">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M3.75 6.75h16.5M3.75 12h16.5m-16.5 5.25h16.5" />
                </svg>
              </div>
              <img src="{{data[activeMsgIndex].userImage}}" class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full object-cover">
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $("#button").click(function() {
      $("#navbar-default").toggleClass('!ml-0')
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer involves inclusion of `javascript` to trigger event `on press` of menubutton.

Steps to follow:

1. Design the desired `overflow/side popup` as you have mentioned in the question and by default hide it.
2. When menu button is clicked, make the `overflow/side popup` show, by unhidding the component.